# Qt 5.14.2 does not file .so file when building

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qml

I struggle for cross compiling for Raspberry pi 4. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04. I builded cross compile platform and I have been run simple quick application. (I created project on PC and I could see output window on Raspberry pi screen).

I want run more big project on Raspberry pi4 with cross compile. I want edit code on my PC and I want see output on Raspberry pi 4. I have been worked this project on Raspberry pi 4 without Qt.

I tried run qmake for .pro file and I compiled the resulting makefile file. It's working. I want do same process with cross compile but I have errors this place. Qt does not find some .so files but I checked and this files are exist on the specified path. I tried add external library,I tried add external library and I tried editing path of `LIBS` and   `INCLUDEPATH` but result did not change.

**P.S.** I used this commands when I building cross compile. https://github.com/PhysicsX/QTonRaspberryPi/blob/main/qt5.14.2onRaspberrypi

My .pro file is:

```
QT += quick widgets serialport multimedia
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


INCLUDEPATH += -I/opt/qt5pi/sysroot/usr/include/opencv2
LIBS += -L/opt/qt5pi/sysroot/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_videostab  -lopencv_features2d

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
    file.cpp \
    gcodesender.cpp \
    movementmanager.cpp \
    usbmanager.cpp \
    imageresizer.cpp \
    serialcommunicator.cpp \
    frameprocessor.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc


# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /home/pi/dev/$${TARGET}/
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    file.h \
    gcodesender.h \
    movementmanager.h \
    usbmanager.h \
    imageresizer.h \
    serialcommunicator.h \
    frameprocessor.h

DISTFILES += \
    theme/DarkTheme_copy.qml \
    theme/WhiteTheme.qml
```

Part of the error is below:

```
linux-gnueabihf/libavformat.so.58, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/qt5pi/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.5.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libvcos.so, needed by /opt/qt5pi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavformat.so.58, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/qt5pi/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.5.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libblas.so.3, needed by /opt/qt5pi/sysroot/lib/libarmadillo.so.9, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/qt5pi/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.5.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: liblapack.so.3, needed by /opt/qt5pi/sysroot/lib/libarmadillo.so.9, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/qt5pi/sysroot/lib/libarmadillo.so.9: undefined reference to `zgemm_'
/opt/qt5pi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarpack.so.2: undefined reference to `clahqr_'
/opt/qt5pi/sysroot/lib/libarmadillo.so.9: undefined reference to `sdot_'
/opt/qt5pi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavcodec.so.58: undefined reference to `vcsm_malloc_cache'
/opt/qt5pi/sysroot/lib/libarmadillo.so.9: undefined reference to `dgehrd_'
/opt/qt5pi/sysroot/lib/libarmadillo.so.9: undefined reference to `zgetrf_'
/opt/qt5pi/sysroot/lib/libarmadillo.so.9: undefined reference to `zggev_'
```

And my compiled output all errors(I'm stuck on the character limit ): https://pastebin.pl/view/cbeede8a

How can I fix error ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide all the details within the question itself not with external links

Comment: @AlanBirtles What else should I add to my question? Sorry I could not understand.

Comment: the error output

Comment: @AlanBirtles I shared output with pastebin. The output include so many characters and web site give me warning to characters limit. If you want I can share a similar part of the error.

Comment: you have to check if symlinks aren't broken or access to files isn't given, supposedly `/sysroot-relativelinks.py sysroot` had to care of it properly but it's worth to check. There is also rare edge case that there is  file with proper timestamp but zero length because rsync failed somehow

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I tried relink but result is same. And I use `chown` command in `/opt` folder for access. Is it true?